# Simulating my location within the emulator for Intellij IDEA 11

Tags: android, intellij-idea, location, simulate

How to simulate my location within the emulator for Intellij IDEA 11,

like using DDMS tool in eclipse ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same DDMS tool in IDEA: `Tools` | `Android` | `DDMS`.